# Save selection of multiple Excel workbooks to one pdf with Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf, win32com

I want to make a pdf somposed by ranges in all Excel-workbooks located in a given folder (folderwithallfiles). All workbooks will have the same structure so the range reference will be the same for all workbooks.

I thought I got it with the script below, but it does not work.

```
import win32com.client as win32 
import glob 
import os 

xlfiles = sorted(glob.glob("*.xlsx")) 
#print "Reading %d files..."%len(xlfiles) 

cwd = "C:\\Users\\user\folderwithallfiles"
#cwd = os.getcwd() 
path_to_pdf = r'C:\\Users\\user\folderwithallfiles\multitest.pdf'
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') 
for xlfile in xlfiles: 
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(cwd+"\\"+xlfile)
    ws = wb.Sheets('sheet 1')
    ws.Range("A1:Q59").Select()

    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code if it works. I have written on the fly. Let me know if you find issues in it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import pdfkit as pdf

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("filepath\file*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

all_data.to_html("filepath\all_data.html)
pdf.from_file("filepath\all_data.html", "filepath\all_data.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not quite do it for me:( Did not get it to work, and I guess using numpy will remove the formatting in Excel, like font, size anc cell colors, that I want to preserve in my final .pdf report?